# Изменить переменную в функции, переданную в аргументе

Tags: javascript

Вот такой пример:

```
function set_one(a){
    a = 1;
}

test = 0;
set_one(test);
alert(test);
```

Можно ли без использования глобальных переменных изменить `test` внутри функции?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tzcc23qo/

Comment: Области видимости в js это позволяют сделать. Вот [результат](https://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/0ovzjq66/). Только код вашей функции должен быть синхронным, к примеру, не использовать запрос к серверу.

Comment: @romeo написав "не используя глобальные переменные" ,я имел ввиду и без области видимости, изменить именно переданую переменную

Comment: @Mr_Epic: ok, только синхронность всё равно необходима.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос зависит от того, что именно вы передаете в функцию.

В JavaScript аргументы могут передаваться либо по ссылке (объекты) либо по значению (скалярные типы). Как следствие, если вы передаете в функцию объект, то изменение *полей* (именно полей, а не самого объекта) этого объекта будет видно и вне функции.

```
var obj = {test: 'str'};
var f = function(a) {
    a.test = 'another str';
};

f(obj);
console.log(obj.test); // Выведет 'another str'
```

В тоже время, вы не можете изменить сам объект:

```
var obj = {test: 'str'};
var f = function(a) {
    a = {test: 'another str'};
};

f(obj);
console.log(obj.test); // Выведет 'str'
```

Если же вы передаете в функцию скаляр, то изменение его значения внутри функции не отразится на глобальном контексте.

```
var i = 0;
var f = function(a) {
    a += 1;
};

f(i);
console.log(i); // выведет "0".
```

Если очень хочется, то скалярные величины можно оборачивать в объект и работать с такими аргументами *по ссылке*. Например так:

```
var i = {val: 0};
var f = function(a) {
    a.val += 1;
};

f(i);
console.log(i.val); // выведет "1".
```

**Замечание**: то, что вы хотите сделать, очень попахивает магией. Возможно стоит рассмотреть другой вариант решения оригинальной проблемы (например, с использованием замыкания).

Comment: Примерно смоделировал на примере, как получается у меня в коде, это оптимальное решение или возможно вы сможете предложить что-то получится, не переставляя функции?  
http://jsfiddle.net/qw89yupq/

Comment: @Mr_Epic, Если вы хотите использовать именно передачу аргумента по ссылке, то ваше решение имеет право на жизнь. Если говорить об оптимальности -- нужен контекст. В вашем пример с JSFiddle, я бы вообще ограничился обычным `return` в функции `more`.

Comment: вот тут более точно показал как у меня всё происходит и то что она много раз изменяется по ходу и вызываем её не мы, а `requestAnimationFrame` http://jsfiddle.net/qw89yupq/1/

Comment: @Mr_Epic, у вас серьезные проблемы с архитектурой приложения. На самом деле, все что вам нужно -- это правильно использовать функции обратного вызова. Я думаю, что вам стоит открыть под это отдельный вопрос.

Comment: на самом деле в примере я очень грубо смоделировал как у меня всё устроенно. Дело в том что приложение на AngularJS.. Ладно, я более мене разобрался, спасибо что уделили время моему вопросу.